# Tracing a WSoD in Joomla

Tags: debugging, joomla, wsod

How do I find out which code section an error occurs in, if the site done on Joomla gives me a White Screen of Death?

I even know which module fails, and under what condition (it is a slideshow module, and it fails when one of the items to display are of video type), but I would like to check what place in the code it fails in, in the hope of perhaps correcting the problem myself (I am not the original developer, and I am not fluent in PHP yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable error reporting in your environment. It is disabled by default due to security concerns. I think the easiest way would be to put the following lines of code in the beginning of your joomla installation's index.php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

After you are done debugging do not forget to remove or comment out those two lines.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Sorry, I need to wait before I can put the site in the needed conditions for the test. I will make sure to accept your answer if it does help when I try it, though. Thanks again for your help.